# Grounded Conductor Sizing

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

OCPD: 400A
System: 480/277V
Ungrounded conductor size: 500kcm

How do I find the minimum size Cu THHN grounded conductor?

I tried using T250. 102(c)(1) from 2017 NEC 70 and I got 1/0 AWG but I am not convinced that I answered the entire question or even if I am on the right track.

I need to know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your post. Are you trying to size the intentionally grounded conductor (neutral) or the equipment grounding conductor (ground wire)?

Comment: What are your loads and how will they be used? It seriously matters. ArchonOSX I assume OP means neutral since they were just in NEC and are using correct NEC lawyertalk for neutral.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming we are talking about copper conductors here and the service is not a parallel feed.

NEC table 250.102(C)(1) is for sizing a service with no overcurrent protection so it is sized by the incoming conductors so it would require a 1/0 copper grounding conductor.

NEC table 250.122 sizes the grounding conductor by its overcurrent protection. So if this is after a 400A breaker, your grounding conductor would be a #2 copper conductor.

I need to make this clear. You are calling for a minimum **grounded conductor** which is a neutral and I am assuming you mean a **grounding conductor** . I am giving you information on sizing a grounding conductor. If you really do mean a neutral you shouldn't downsize it from a 500 Kcmil without professional assistance since it would require a load study.

Hope this helps.